# Finding minimum of a distance function using matlab

Tags: matrices, optimization, numerical-methods, problem-solving, matlab

I have a function for that I want to find the minimum. The function calculates the distance between two sets where a set is defined as matix of row vectors $ D = [ d_1, d_2, ..., d_n]$, $d_n$ is a $m \times 1$ vector. The distance metric is:

$$
d(x_1,x_2) = -(x_1 - x_2)^T G (x_1 - x_2) + x_1^T M x_2
$$
$M$ and $G$ are $m \times m$ matrices.

In order to make this distance function suitable for sets I need to find the weighted mean for both sets ( $Da$ where $a$ is a weighting vector of $n \times 1$)  that minimize the distance:

$$
\min_{a,b}   - (D_1a - D_2 b)^T G (D_1a - D_2 b) + (D_1a)^T M D_2 b
$$
with 
$$
\sum a_i = 1, \sum b_i = 1
$$

My question is, which algorithm can I use to find $a,b$ and how can I implement it in Matlab?

Comment: Am I right, that $-(D_1a-D_2b)^TG(D_1a-D_2b)+...$ is a vector?

Comment: If you mean after adding everything together then no, it is only a single number. This function is basically only the Euclidean distance (Mahalanobis distance) plus the inner product of two vectors. Where this vectors are the weighted mean of two matrices $D_1a, D_2b$.

Comment: Ah yes, right. $D$ is $m\times n$ and $a$ is $n\times 1$.

Comment: Since this is nonlinear problem, `fmincon` is always an option. However, that function requires the optimization toolbox whose cost cannot be justified for a lot of people. I'd recommend trying [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/), which is meant for convex programming of all types. It is very easy to use, free, and very effective and efficient for most types of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have fmincon but I am not exactly sure how I can solve my problem with that, especially how can I define the $sum a_i = 1$ constrain. Could you give me a hint?